# React navigation bottom tab navigator change background dynamically

Tags: react-native, react-navigation

I faced a problem with react navigation's bottom tab navigator. So I have a dark theme in my app, and when I switch between the themes, all the colors changing in the app, except the bottom tab navigator. It's NOT re-rendering itself. What can cause this any idea?

It's re-rendering and changes the colors when i take an anction on it, like pressing to another tab.

```
export const PostBottomNavigator = ({ navigation, route }) => {
return (
    <B_Post.Navigator
        initialRouteName="PostHome"
        labeled={false}
        headerMode="float"
        shifting={true}
        style={{ backgroundColor: colorsComponent.defaultBackgroundColor }}
        barStyle={styles().bar}
        screenOptions={({ route }) => ({
            headerShown: true,
            tabBarIcon: ({ focused, color, size }) => {
                const { name } = route;
                let icon;
                switch (name) {
                    case "PostHome":
                        icon = focused ? imagesMain.homeS_selected : imagesMain.homeS;
                        break;
                    case "Discover":
                        icon = focused
                            ? imagesMain.discover_selected
                            : imagesMain.discover;
                        break;
                    case "ModalPlaceHolder":
                        icon = focused ? imagesMain.share_selected : imagesMain.share;
                        break;
                    case "HomeTown":
                        icon = focused
                            ? imagesMain.homeTown_selected
                            : imagesMain.homeTown;
                        break;
                    case "Profile":
                        return <BottomProfileImage />;
                        break;
                    default:
                        icon = focused ? imagesMain.lastList : imagesMain.lastList;
                        break;
                }
                return <Image style={{ width: 28, height: 28 }} source={icon} />;
            },
        })}
    >
        <B_Post.Screen name="PostHome" component={Timeline} />
        <B_Post.Screen name="Discover" component={Discover} />
        <B_Post.Screen
            name="ModalPlaceHolder"
            listeners={({ navigation }) => ({
                tabPress: (event) => {
                    event.preventDefault();
                    navigation.navigate("NewPost");
                },
            })}
            component={ModalPlaceHolder}
        />
        <B_Post.Screen name="HomeTown" component={Profile} />
        <B_Post.Screen
            name="Profile"
            component={ProfileStackNavigator}
            initialParams={{ type: "social" }}
        />
    </B_Post.Navigator>
);
```

};

Comment: How do you switch theme?

Comment: I hold the theme value on MobX store. The value is light or dark. And  i grab that value in the files where i hold the colors and  icon images. I have separate folders for both modes called named dark and light and they are being called by the theme. I hope you get the idea

Comment: And how your navigator get the updated theme? Is your navigator connected to store?

Comment: No, the colors themselves are getter functions they are getting updated. Its actually working but like i said just requires to take an action

Comment: Yeah but how your navigator will be notified about the update and re-render it self?

Comment: Actually thats the question that im looking to answer for :)

Comment: You need to use a hook or connect your navigator to store so it can update on theme changes. Could you please setup a reproducible snack so I can look?